# Is it possible to replace a python file while its running

Tags: python

I have a single python file that takes about an hour to run. Can I replace the whole file while its running without issues? I am aware if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296977/what-will-happen-if-i-modify-a-python-script-while-its-running) it does not address the concern of the python file being totally replaced with a new one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate - from a file system standpoint every edit of a file results in its complete replacement, so your question is correctly answered there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `.py` file is read into memory, compiled and run without further access.