# Run torque job while editing the source file

Tags: git, torque

I have a project using git as the source control tool, with a default branch named `dev`. And I can run that as a job on a torque server. My question is, **while the job using the code from branch `dev` is running**, is it safe to create a new branch, then edit some piece of code and run that new branch?

I guess this is related to how program is loaded into memory and maybe also the internal logic of torque. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is actually not really specific to either GIT or TORQUE.

What you (I guess) want to do is change a scripts source while it is running.

As you already guessed, this is heavily dependent on your program.
E.g.

- if you program is a shell script, this will not work, at least not by default. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110663/bash-is-automatically-reloading-injecting-updates-into-a-running-script-upon-s
- if your application is a Python script, changing the script's source should work fine: [What will happen if I modify a Python script while it's running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296977/what-will-happen-if-i-modify-a-python-script-while-its-running)

You will have to check the implications for your technology stack. 
However, if this is a more complex application, there could be a lot of pitfalls.

I would recommend finding another solution. If your GIT repository is small, a straightforward approach would be to just check out multiple repository instances i.e. to different folders.